# This is undefined in $watch

Tags: angularjs

I have a watcher:

```
this.$scope.name = this.$state.current.name;
this.$scope.$watch(name, function () {
    this.selectedTabIndex = this.$scope.getSelectedTabIndex();
});
```

When the code runs:

> Cannot read property '$scope' of undefined

How do I make `this` available inside the `$watch`?

Comment: If you're doing this inside of a controller that is using the controllerAs syntax, its recommended (based off the angular style guide) to do `var vm = this;` at the top of your controller and then you can access everything from `vm`.  This will prevent issues where functions create their own scope and you can no longer access `this` or `this` is no longer what you think it is.   (note `vm` is an example in this case, use whatever variable you wish, ideally what you use for controllerAs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use an arrow function instead as the `function` creates its own scope for `this`.

```
this.$scope.name = this.$state.current.name;
this.$scope.$watch(name, () => {
    this.selectedTabIndex = this.$scope.getSelectedTabIndex();
});
```

Comment: Yea that makes sense. But for some reason my `this.$state.current.name` isn't changed in the `$watch.